# regular expression: can ".*" match the same string as the ".*?" do?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

From [Dive into Python3](http://www.diveintopython3.net/advanced-iterators.html),

```
re.findall(' s.*? s', "The sixth sick sheikh's sixth sheep's sick.")
```

It explains that :

> The regular expression looks for a space, an s, and then the shortest possible series of any character (.*?), then a space, then another s.

My question is : can `.*` match the same string as `.*?` do?

Comment: Do you mean in general, or in this specific case?

Comment: *can* it? yes. *will* it? it depends on the pattern.  Read up on greedy vs. non-greedy matching. The long story short is `.*` is greedy and will first match everything it can, and then work its way backwards giving up only what it must to fulfill the rest of the pattern (last instance of rest of pattern).  `.*?` is non-greedy and will match forward until it hits first instance of rest of pattern.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. If the greedy match is identical to the lazy match.

```
>>> re.findall(' s.*? s', "The sixth sheik") == re.findall(' s.* s', "The sixth sheik")                                                                                                                                     
True
```

But if greedy match is longer, you will get different results.

```
>>> re.findall(' s.*? s', "The sixth sick sheik") == re.findall(' s.* s', "The sixth sick sheik")                                                                                                                           
False
```

Answer (score 1):

> My question is : can .* match the same string as .*? do?

Yes, if there is only one pattern like `' sany s'` exists. That is, exactly one match found.

**Example:**

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'foo sgh s'
>>> re.findall(r' s.*? s', s)
[' sgh s']
>>> re.findall(r' s.* s', s)
[' sgh s']
```

Answer (score 1):

**No**

check it over [here](http://www.regexr.com/)

[image: Results with Question mark]

When remove Question mark:
[image: After question mark removed]